# Style breaks when x:Key is added

Tags: wpf, xaml

Under `<Window.Resources>`, I have the following style defined:

```
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="22" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="125" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
    </Style>
```

It works fine until I needed to inherit the style on another style

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
```

Which means I need to add the `x:Key=TextBoxStyle` to the Text box style above.
But when I do this, the styling for the text box breaks altogether.
I tried doing the same to Button styling, and the same thing happens, where the style will break if I add a key to it.

The only solution I thought of is to individually add the style to the elements, but that is what I am trying not to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not need to add `x:Key` to reference it:

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
```

Comment: I see. I'm still curious though, why did the style break when I add a key?

Comment: @Edwin: It does not break, if you do not specify `x:Key` the key is set to the type of the control, which makes it apply to all controls of that type, you can do this manually as well. If you specify another key it simply does not apply automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Well to provide a better understandability and maintainance, I would prefer the following approach. IMHO, another programmer could get better into the code, if the implicities are reduced to a minimum.

```
<Style x:Key="BasicTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <!--some settings here-->
</Style>

<!--Declare BasicTextBoxStyle as default style for TextBoxes-->
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource BasicTextBoxStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"/>

<!--Create some special style based on the basic style-->
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource BasicTextBoxStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
    <!--some more specific settings-->
</Style>
```

Just my two cents...